# Mega menu div doesn't hover over YouTube embed on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover, embed

If you hover over the ***More*** menu item using IE on [this page](http://the-artifice.com/the-garden-of-words-preview/), you will notice that the drop down div displays behind the YouTube embedment. I have tested this on IE8 and IE9 so far.

To solve this, I have tried:

- Playing around with `z-index` without success.
- Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147216/insert-div-over-flash-in-ie) question. The answer details that I need to set the
  following attribute to the flash embed code `<param name="wmode"
  value="transparent" />`. The site is powered by Wordpress and I may
  need to change core files to test this which I am avoiding.

How can I make the div hover properly on IE? It works fine on FF, Chrome etc.

Comment: I'm not seeing your problem, IE10 and Chrome 25, when the video is playing or not the More... dropdown menu is always in front.

Comment: @GordonsBeard It works fine on all browsers besides IE8/IE9.

Answer (score 2):

```
?wmode=transparent&rel=0
```

Add this to iframe src that should work

Comment: How would I go about doing that? That would mean that I will need to edit the code for the Wordpress `embed` shortcode...?

Comment: you need to put that youtube video with this src
`<iframe width="578" height="325" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/udDIkl6z8X0?wmode=transparent&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: I understand your solution, however, do you know how I would go about to add that to the Wordpress `embed` shortcode?

Comment: I do not exactly know how you put your video there but if you are putting the link so just put that link with those parameters