# External javascript file can't add div on top of everything

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making javascript program which adds div to some pages (as external script). The problem is I don't have access to html code of this pages - my client just puts `/script src=""/` on it and I'm stuck:
My div have to slide from bottom of a page, so I'm using fixed position and here it is - my div is hiding below flash elements of pages.

So what I need:
No matter how page looks like, what have in layout - I have to make my new sliding div  showing over everything without making any changes to html code of page itself.

No idea. Don't know how page looks like - can't use `position:relative` i guess. Just flash is over my div.

//Only in Chrome my div is over flash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the way IE renders some elements and plugins. See [Insert div over flash in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147216/insert-div-over-flash-in-ie) for more information.

The challenge in your case is that you are not able to edit the source of the page. I have been involved in similar cases before and the only solution we found at the time was to replace the `div` with and `iframe` and then place the content of the div there.